# What is the implication of not using X509Store.Close method?

Tags: .net, x509certificate, x509certificate2

If I keep initializing `X509Store` certificate stores and don't use their [`Close()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store.close?view=netframework-4.5) method, what is the implication of this?

In the code example [given in documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store.close?view=netframework-4.5), they don't use `try..finally` block to make a call to `Close` method. If this certificate store is something that needs to be freed, why does not the API of the class designed to derive from `IDisposable` or why does not this class have a implicit destructor called when object goes out of scope?

Answer (score 16):

In .NET 4.6, `X509Store` was modified and now implementing `IDisposable`.

The `Dispose` implementation is calling the `Close()`.

From [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store#remarks):

> Starting with the .NET Framework 4.6, this type implements the IDisposable interface. When you have finished using the type, you should dispose of it either directly or indirectly.

Comment: To confirm what @Shay said about Dispose calling Close, see https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/security/system/security/cryptography/x509/x509store.cs,5f32dc1ea67a9cb7

Answer (score 1):

Internally, the Close method release the handle pointing to the unmanaged object.

```
public void Close()
{
    if ((this.m_safeCertStoreHandle != null) && !this.m_safeCertStoreHandle.IsClosed)
    {
        this.m_safeCertStoreHandle.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I'd rather call the Close method to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: why don't they do this in the destructor, that was my question actually. btw where did you get the source code from?

Comment: In .Net IDisposable is prefered over destructors.See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456213/destructor-vs-idisposable
I got the code using Ilspy decompiler. 
http://ilspy.net/

Comment: So why this API is not designed with IDisposable do you think?

Comment: I can't tell without taking a deeper look at the sources. Even Microsoft code isn't perfect. But for you  it's a shorter writing to call Close() than a full using or try/finally block! :-)