# Certificate with private key .Net Core

Tags: .net-core, x509certificate, private-key, identityserver4

Anyone know how to create a `X509Certificate2` with a private key in .net core, there is no property `X509Certificate2.PrivateKey` which I can set?

I have the following code

`byte[] rawData = ....;
var x509Certificate2 = new X509Certificate2(rawData.ToArray(), "XXXX");
bool hasPK = x509Certificate2.HasPrivateKey; // is false`

How do I add my PK to the certificate above so that I can pass it into my IdentityServer 4 signing mechanism using `services.AddIdentityServer().AddSigningCredential(x509Certificate2);`

Any help on either topic is appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET Standard - Merge a certificate and a private key into a .pfx file programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44465574/net-standard-merge-a-certificate-and-a-private-key-into-a-pfx-file-programma)

Comment: That's using a preview version of a technology, is there no way to do this with the current released version (.net core 1.1)?

Comment: No, not using framework types. You need them pre-associated in a PFX. Windows NetFX, BouncyCastle, OpenSSL, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Probably you want to have a look at this answered question first: [How would I generate the Identity Server signing certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35880187/how-would-i-generate-the-identity-server-signing-certificate)

Then you will find that `makecert` is obsolete. Instead you could use PowerShell's: [New-SelfSignedCertificate](https://technet.microsoft.com/itpro/powershell/windows/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate) or maybe an extension/helper of that: [New-SelfSignedCertificateEx](https://www.sysadmins.lv/projects/pspki/New-SelfSignedCertificateEx.aspx)

Once the certificate is generated, you could load it into the Identity Server as described above.